# Why does this print 12 times?

Tags: perl

I am learning Perl's multithreading. My code:

```
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

$howmany = 10;
$threads = 5;

$to = int($howmany / $threads);

for (0 .. $threads) {$trl[$_] = threads->create(\&main, $_);}
for (@trl) {$_->join;}

sub main {
    for (1 .. $to) {
        print "test\n";
    }
}

exit(0);
```

I want to print the word *test* `$howmany` times in `$threads` threads.
This code prints *test* 12 times. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Then I think you want `for (0..$threads-1)` or `for (1..$threads)`, not `for (0..$threads)`

:-)

Comment: Exactly! I have a few hours I can not understand the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11):

May I suggest an alternate approach?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads       ;#qw( async );
use Thread::Queue qw( );

my $num_workers    = 5;
my $num_work_units = 10;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

# Create workers
my @workers;
for (1..$num_workers) {
   push @workers, async {
      while (defined(my $unit = $q->dequeue())) {
         print("$unit\n");
      }
   };
}

# Create work
for (1..$num_work_units) {
   $q->enqueue($_);
}

# Tell workers they are no longer needed.
$q->enqueue(undef) for @workers;

# Wait for workers to end
$_->join() for @workers;
```

Advantages:

- More scalable
- Works even if $num_work_units / $num_workers is not an integer.
- Doesn't assume that all work units take the same amount of time to complete.

Output:

```
1
5
2
8
9
10
7
3
4
6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for( 0..$threads )
```

runs **6** times: 0,1,2,3,4,5