# Using maximum threads on multicore cpu

Tags: perl

at first, my perlskills are limited so please keep that in mind. ;)

I have written a perlscript which indexes a directory and does something for each file in it.

Processing a file takes some time. Between 1 - 5 mins each at a cpu load nearly 100% (one core). My idea is, cause i have a quadcore cpu, to process more then one file at once, which leads me to perl threads.

So here are my questions.

1) Is my assumption right, that perl threads are allocated automatically to multiple cores?

2) I found this code example which does what i need, i think but i cannot figure out, how to keep always only 8 threads active. The example starts a static count of threads and is done when they are processed. However, in my case i have, lets say, 50 files to process but only 8 threads should be active at the same time.

So it should be like this: 
Read the directory, start 8 threads for the 8 first files and keep 8 threads working until all files are processed.

```
#!/usr/local/roadm/bin/perl
# This is compiled with threading support

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

print "Starting main program\n";

my @threads;
for ( my $count = 1; $count <= 10; $count++) {
        my $t = threads->new(\&sub1, $count);
        push(@threads,$t);
}   
foreach (@threads) {
        my $num = $_->join;
        print "done with $num\n";
}   
print "End of main program\n";

sub sub1 {
        my $num = shift;
        print "started thread $num\n";
        sleep $num;
        print "done with thread $num\n";
        return $num;
}
```

Source: https://wiki.bc.net/atl-conf/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20548191

I searched some hours now but did not find an example, how to do this. Would be nice when someone could give me a hint how to start.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use < pre > and < /pre >. Please read the FAQ on how to format code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good solution to your problem using [Thread::Queue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread::Queue) and number of workers can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221868/why-does-this-print-12-times#6222082).

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what i was looking for. At first i was a bit confused but now it works. So this is my final solution. Anyway, now i have to figure out how to handle parallel sqlite access but thats a different problem. :) Thx again

Answer (score 6):

Threads in perl are heavyweight; they take time and cpu to start and time, cpu, and memory to share data between them (and require that you carefully check what modules you are using for thread safety).

You are often much better off forking; [Parallel::ForkManager](http://p3rl.org/Parallel::ForkManager) makes this easy.

Comment: Hi ysth, i'm fine with forking too but can you confirm that a forked process is automatically allocated to a "free" core? Second question: Do you know about a good example of forking WITHOUT an extra module? I try to do as much work as possible without extra modules to keep the dependencies low. The link i posted in the main post has also a good forking example but there i have to same problem as with the threads example. Its only for a static thread count.

Comment: yes, different forked processes can run on different cores.  forking is easy without an extra module, but once you add in the complexity of limiting the number running, waiting for all to finish, retrieving returned results, etc, you might as well use a module that's done all that already.  P::FM's actual code is only 185 lines long, but there's a lot packed in there.

Comment: Fair enough :) I will at first dig into the other answer, cause it has no extra dependencies. Anyway, thx for your comment, i will decide which answer is the "final" one later. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;
use threads;

my $cpu ||= 5;
my @threads;
my @all_target = qw /1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9/;

while(my($t,$job) = each @all_target){
    $t = threads -> create(\&do,$job);
    push @threads,$t;

    if(@threads == $cpu or $t == $#all_target){
        for(@threads){
            $_ -> join();
        }
        @threads = ();
    }
}`enter code here`

sub do{
    my $be_do = shift;
    print"$be_do\n";
    sleep 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;
use threads;

my $cpu ||= 5;
my @threads;
my @all_target = qw /1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9/;

while(my($t,$job) = each @all_target){

    my $thread = threads -> create(\&do,$job);
    push @threads,$thread;

    if(@threads == $cpu or $t == $#all_target){
        for(@threads){
            $_ -> join();
            print "$_ join\n";
        }
        @threads = ();
    }
}

sub do{
    my $be_do = shift;

    print"$be_do\n";
    sleep 2;
#   $cmd = "do what";
#   system("$cmd");
}
```